# For the the union of 2 conditions, use IF or EVALUATE in COBOL?

Tags: cobol

"If it works, don't touch it"...I understand. That said, the code I'm extending is studded with blocks like this:

```
 EVALUATE TRUE ALSO TRUE
  WHEN FOO-YES ALSO BAR-YES
   PERFORM ACTION
  WHEN OTHER
   SET ERROR TO TRUE
 END-EVALUATE
```

To my inexperienced eye, IF seems clearer:

```
 IF FOO-YES AND BAR-YES
   PERFORM ACTION
 ELSE
   SET ERROR TO TRUE
 ENDIF
```

When writing new functionality, is there a reason to prefer EVALUATE over IF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to prefer EVALUATE over IF.  I do, but I don't have a good reason for it.  I try to code so it is easy for the maintainer to understand, but there are going to be cases where the logic is complex and you end up with constructs like...

```
EVALUATE TRUE ALSO TRUE ALSO TRUE
  WHEN INITIAL-STATE ALSO ANY ALSO ANY 
       PERFORM 0100-INITIALIZE
       PERFORM 1000-DISPLAY-MENU
  WHEN MENU-DISPLAYED ALSO DFHRESP(NORMAL) ALSO UPDATE-REQUESTED
       PERFORM 2000-DO-THE-UPDATE
       EXEC CICS RETURN END-EXEC
  [...and so forth...]
END-EVALUATE
```

[Somewhere](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein#1930s) there's a quote about how things should be as simple as possible, but no simpler.  There are, of course, many ways to code the same logic.  Different people find different constructs easier to understand.  Lots of arguments occur because of those differences.

Answer (score 2):

You read it correctly.  "True ALSO True" is a very odd thing to code.

Often you will see an "Evaluate True", in which case the when conditions all act EXACTLY like IF statements.  Using ALSO introduces some possible oddities, as it isn't just like the CASE statements from all the other languages.

A nicer way to write this is:

```
Evaluate true
  when FOO-YES and BAR-YES
    perform action
  when other 
    set error to true
End-Evaluate
```

Granted, TRUE ALSO TRUE is very easy to understand, but you could have TRUE ALSO WS-BLAH-BLAH and it could get confusing.  The Cobol Evaluate verb is very powerful, and sometimes easy to shoot yourself in the foot with.  That said, it is very powerful and will let you do alot.

It is often the case that convoluted IF's that don't nest cleanly can be fixed up nicely with a well written Evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

I may say that makes the life easy in certain situations. Say for instance where we'll get to add another condition based on which we may need to `PERFORM` different chunk of code; in that case appending another `WHEN` would be easy rather than adjusting the conditions on `IF`. Here are the points when compared `WHEN` against adjusting conditions on `IF`:

- We would have a feasibility to provide as many `WHEN(s)` as we want based on the `PARAs` to be performed.
- `IF` conditions are prone to mistakes while working with `OR` or `AND` parameters
- Also `WHEN` gives clear picture of how things flow where as we may have to adjust our glasses while analyzing `IF`(s). [This may happen when we have complicated loops, but as an efficient programmer we ought to forecast such scenarios]
- Last but not the least, retrofitting back the code to previous state would be easy with less number of `IFs`.

But in your current case, i dont feel much clarity and as well difference between `EVALUATE` and `IF`. So, go for the one which makes you happy :)

Answer (score 0):

To me it all comes down to readability (and hence, simpler maintenance later on).

When I look at the 2 code segments in your question, I find the `IF` block far more readable.

In 22 years of Cobol programming I have never used an `ALSO` in an `EVALUATE`.
And using an `EVALUATE` block for a simple binary true/false test seems a bit obtuse to me.

But don't get me wrong, I love `EVALUATE`s when used appropriately. When I started programming in Java 6 years ago, `EVALUATE` was the thing I missed most. Sure, Java has `switch`, but that can't be used as flexibly as `EVALUATE`.

Consider the following code segment:

```
IF ACTION = "START"
   PERFORM START
ELSE IF ACTION = "STOP"
   PERFORM STOP
ELSE IF ACTION = "PROCESS" AND FILE-NAME = "A"
   PERFORM PROCESS-A-FILE
ELSE IF ACTION = "PROCESS" AND FILE-NAME = "B"
   PERFORM PROCESS-B-FILE
ELSE IF ACTION = "RESET"
   PERFORM RESET
ELSE
   PERFORM INVALID-ACTION-ERROR.
```

This collection of `IF` statements has some real problems. Without adding 5 `END-IF`s to the end of it, you have to end the block with a full-stop. But you wouldn't be able to do that if the code was inside a `PERFORM UNTIL` ... `END-PERFORM` block, say. While this example is fairly simple, in a more complicated (and longer) example, it could get tricky to figure out which `ELSE` goes with which `IF`.

This is crying out to be put in an `EVALUATE TRUE` block, thus:

```
EVALUATE TRUE
   WHEN ACTION = "START"
      PERFORM START
   WHEN ACTION = "STOP"
      PERFORM STOP
   WHEN ACTION = "PROCESS" AND FILE-NAME = "A"
      PERFORM PROCESS-A-FILE
   WHEN ACTION = "PROCESS" AND FILE-NAME = "B"
      PERFORM PROCESS-B-FILE
   WHEN ACTION = "RESET"
      PERFORM RESET
   WHEN OTHER
      PERFORM INVALID-ACTION-ERROR
END-EVALUATE
```

Changing this `EVALUATE` to have `TRUE ALSO TRUE` would make it far less readable, and it really isn't necessary.